# ListView does not show content

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, adapter

I try to retrieve data from `firebase` and use an `adapter` to show them in `listview`. 
Everything is ok with retrieving data, I checked through debugger, however nothing is shown.
Here is updated *resource_layout.xml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/borders">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewBooks"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

*updated resource_item.xml:*

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/author"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

*ResourceAdapter.java:*

```
public class ResourceAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Books> {

    private Activity context;
    private List<Books> bookList;

    public ResourceAdapter(Activity context, List<Books> bookList){
        super(context, R.layout.resource_item, bookList);
        this.context = context;
        this.bookList = bookList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.resource_item, null, true);

        TextView textViewName = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView textViewAuthor = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.author);
        TextView textViewDate = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.date);

        Books book = bookList.get(position);
        textViewName.setText(book.getName());
        textViewAuthor.setText(book.getAuthor());
        textViewDate.setText(String.valueOf(book.getDate()));

        return listViewItem;
    }
}
```

*ResourceActivity.Java:*

```
public class Resource extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseReference databaseBooks;
    ListView listViewBooks;
    List<Books> bookList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.resource_layout);

        databaseBooks = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("books");

        bookList = new ArrayList<>();
        listViewBooks = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewBooks);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        databaseBooks.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                bookList.clear();

                for (DataSnapshot bookSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Books book = bookSnapshot.getValue(Books.class);
                    bookList.add(book);
                }

                ResourceAdapter adapter = new ResourceAdapter(Resource.this, bookList);
                listViewBooks.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ListView` height is `0dp` and it has a weight. It will not work on `RelativeLayout`. Change it like that.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewBooks"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

**UPDATE:**

Change Row Layout like that. Remove `weight` parameters from `TextViews` and set `layout_height` of LinearLayout as `wrap_content`. Height calculations may be cause the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/author"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**UPDATE 2:** Try to change adapter's getView() method like below.

```
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView==null){
        // inflate the layout
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.resource_item, null, false);
    }


    TextView textViewName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView textViewAuthor = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.author);
    TextView textViewDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);

    Books book = bookList.get(position);
    textViewName.setText(book.getName());
    textViewAuthor.setText(book.getAuthor());
    textViewDate.setText(String.valueOf(book.getDate()));

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: well, I did as you said, but the layout still doesn't show any data

Comment: @CristinaTincu first, Your ListView layout parameters was wrong. If still not working, something else wrong too. Check my answer, updated.

Comment: thanks, but it's still not working, I've updated xml files as you said

Comment: @CristinaTincu then check my update 2, modified your adapter.

Comment: I used Log.d and saw that convertView is always null, in your update 2 listViewItem is not defined so I've tried to replace it with convertView and also tried to add if body to previous version...can you tell me, please, in general, is my adapter written right?

Comment: @CristinaTincu sorry, I made a mistake, because tried to answer fast. Updated and fixed mistake. listViewItem replaced with convertView.

Comment: thanks a lot, works perfectly...finally I can continue with design

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `XML`. Your parent layout is `RelativeLayout` and you are using `android:layout_weight="1"` and `android:layout_height="0dp"`.

**You can use `ListView` inside `RelativeLayout` as below:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/borders">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewBooks"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**You can also use `LinearLayout` as below:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/borders"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewBooks"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />
</<LinearLayout>
```

Comment: well, I did as you said, but the layout still doesn't show any data